# installing ubuntu with windows

Tags: linux, windows, installation, virtualbox

I am a Windows 7 user and now I want to use linux. However I am beginner for linux. Currently I have linux mint in a usb and load it from there. The problem is, it doesn't save stuff like everytime I have to enter my wifi password, or change the default search to google, etc etc. Now I am  thinking of installing ubuntu alongside windows. Now after googling a little I realized that I can do it in 2 ways: Using a windows installer, or Using something called a virtual box. My question is, which option should I choose and why? What is a virtual box anyway? Also, is [this](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads) the right link? I need the 64 bit version. Shall I choose the first one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with a virtual machine is that it is running your native OS and another "virtual" OS; as you can imagine, this can be slow. Booting up your virtual OS also takes longer seeing as you functionally need to boot two OSs rather than one.

In terms of dual booting (installing an OS alongside your native OS -- in this case Windows), the resultant OS typically will run faster and won't be bogged down as much. If you have a lot of RAM you might not notice the speed loss though. That being said, it is much easier to install multiple virtual machines than it is to install multiple OSs; your hard drive won't be chaotically partitioned since virtual machines don't need separate partitions.

Comment: It also should be noted that using VMs let's you "play" with various OSs more; you can add and delete them willy-nilly without having to worry about messing up your main OS. This might be a good route to take before establishing what *nix you want.

Answer (score 3):

virtual box allows you to run an OS over the one you are currently working in. You must download virtual box for windows those links are for linux,ubuntu etc.. You might wanna use http://dlc.sun.com.edgesuite.net/virtualbox/4.3.6/VirtualBox-4.3.6-91406-Win.exe link instead.